# What is the meaning of this integral?

Tags: complex-integration

Does anyone know the meaning of this type of integral? $\displaystyle{\int  f(z) \,\overline {dz}}$.

I think this means $\displaystyle{\int u\,dx + v\,dy+i\int v\,dx -u\,dy}$ where $f=u + iv$

Comment: I would say that you're correct.